# How to replace placeholder images with local images in Buefy Carousel?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, buefy, gridsome

I have copied the Buefy carousel component from https://buefy.org/documentation/carousel#carousel-list into my Gridsome project. The carousel displays correctly with its supplied placeholder images. These are in an array in the data() segment eg

```
items: [
                {
                    title: 'Slide 1',
                    image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/0/1230/500'
                },
```

Now I want my images, not the Buefy placeholder ones.
I cannot find the right way to target my local images. I have tried lots of things including

```
items: [
                {
                    title: 'Slide 1',
                    image: require("@/assets/img/gallery/sheep/sheep2.jpg")
                },
```

My attempts either break the carousel or display a broken link within it.

Comment: did you try with `require("@./assets/img/gallery/sheep/sheep2.jpg")`? Where is the location of the assets directory compared to the directory where the main js is?

Comment: Or without require, just as relative src? `"../assets/img/gallery/sheep/sheep2.jpg"`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I did a new build (in my case "gridsome develop") after inserting my own image paths. Then this worked fine -

```
items: [
    {
      title: "Slide 1",
      image: require("@/assets/img/gallery/sheep/sheep1.jpg")
    },
```